# Pagination with POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, post

I have an advanced search form which I switched from method=GET to method=POST as the url became too long for the browser.

Now I was using a gem (will_pagination) for pagination. The problem is that the gem used to merge params and update page_no to generate the link, and while this worked for a GET based form, it obviously doesn't work for a POST Method based form.  For eg-: `http://localhost:3000/orders/advanced_search` changes to `http://localhost:3000/orders/advanced_search?page=2` which fails as this is a post call, and not a get call.

What are my alternatives?

Is there a way to make the link send a POST call while merging params on RAILS?

Another thing, I was thinking was make the page link click associated with an on-click action which updates a hidden page field in my form, and then re-submits. Hoping this part of jquery isn't that hard.

Comment: I'm always keep the submit filters on session and only receives the param 'page' to use at SQL queries...when user 're-submit' the page data I only overwrite session filter content and reset 'page' var.

Comment: I don't believe a Rails controller cares whether a particular value was GET or POST. I'm pretty sure `params[:whatever]` will work whether the request was GET or POST.

Comment: Yup it will. But within my controller I am making a RestClient.post call, which fails when the params get added to the url itself. Plus when you click a link directly like the one mentioned, you lose all your other params. :-(

Comment: If you add an hidden value in the form, wich would contain page_no.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but not optimized.
In the PHP, before will_pagination is called, put this :

```
$_GET['page_no'] = $_POST['page_no'];
```

Comment: Suppose there are pages generated as 1,2,3,....1500. Now when he click page 3, the link is http://localhost:3000/orders/advanced_search?page=3, and in this process I lose my previous params. Where should I be making the change? I can't let the user click the link like this, as it won't work.